Even horizontal spacing in enumitem inline lists
I would like to have an equally (horizontally-)spaced inline list, like

(1) 0.4 (some spaces) 　　　　　　　　　　　　(2) 12.372 (some spaces),

so that each [item and its spaces] will take account of the same width.
The closest I have now is the following:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    Please express the following numbers in fractions:

    \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*), itemjoin=\hspace*{\stretch{1}}, after=\hspace*{\stretch{1}}]
        \item $0.4$
        \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}

, where I use itemjoin=\hspace*{\stretch{1}}, after=\hspace*{\stretch{1}} to tug in spaces of equal sizes for each item.
However, different items may have different lengths; some may be longer, then the corresponding [item together with the spaces] will be longer as well.
(For instance, in the example above, item (2) would start earlier than right in the middle since its content is lengthier.)
Is there a way to fix this (hopefully without leaving enumerate*)?

that code won't produce a separate paragraph for the list. it is just part of the flow of text. so the first item is unlikely to be at the beginning of a line and the final unlikely to be at the end of one. so it isn't clear what you want this to look like. you say you want to stay in inline mode, but the result you want isn't consistent with that.

Yeah you're right, I didn't make things clear enough. I have edited the code to make the enumerate* a separate paragraph; and I also edited the question as well.

I think you are looking for tasks. but your current code gives an error because Environment enumerate* undefined. please fix.

To use enumerate*, you need to give the inline package option to enumitem. However, I don't think enumitem is the tool you want here. Instead, consider tasks which is designed for this and uses a syntax inspired partly by enumitem's.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
Please express the following numbers in fractions:

\begin{tasks}[label=(\arabic*),label-width=20pt](3)
  \task $0.4$
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task $0.4$
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task A much longer item for comparison.
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task $0.4$
  \task A much longer item for comparison.
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \task $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
\end{tasks}


\end{document}



A tagged PDF compatible alternative using the new enumext package:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumext}

\begin{document}
Please express the following numbers in fractions:

\begin{enumext*}[label=(\arabic*), widest=99,columns=3,columns-sep=5pt]
  \item $0.4$
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item $0.4$
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item A much longer item for comparison.
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item $0.4$
  \item A much longer item for comparison.
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
  \item $12.3\overline{72}$ %(maybe some lengthier stuff)
\end{enumext*}


\end{document}


